# Filling Styles using a single Plot in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

Could I specify different filling colors for  within a single plot like the bellow or would I need to "Show" several Plots ? Let`s say I would like the filling style to be the same as the PlotStyle.

```
priorMean = 50;
priorVar = 100;

llhMean = 30;
llhVar = 40;

postMean=35.71;
postVar=28.57;


Plot[
     Evaluate@MapThread[
     Function[{\[Mu], \[Sigma]},
     PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], Sqrt[\[Sigma]]], x]],
     {{priorMean, llhMean, postMean}, {priorVar, llhVar, postVar}}],
{x, 0, 100}, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't `FillingStyle` do what you want?

Comment: 500 I am curious: I thought you would like my answer, but no comment.  Does it not work for your application?

Comment: @Mr. It is ! I have had that deadline that disabled me to dig into it yet. But i was actually thinking that this along with 2 others of your solution regarding Graphics represent a nice philosophy of setting things "in the rock" I just need to ask you questions about it  ! But I do like it !

Comment: Okay.  I have gotten used to your friendly "Thank you" notes on good answers, but I see now that you didn't give that to anyone on this question.  Good luck with the deadline!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to use `FillingStyle` to fill in. I think you got stuck in the syntax for `FillingStyle`, which is *not* the same as that for `PlotStyle`, although you'd expect it to be. You'll have to assign a color for each curve as `FillingStyle -> {1 -> color1, 2 -> color2}`, etc. Here's an example:

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue};
Plot[Evaluate@
  MapThread[
   Function[{\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], Sqrt[\[Sigma]]], x]], {{priorMean, 
     llhMean, postMean}, {priorVar, llhVar, postVar}}], {x, 0, 100}, 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> colors, 
 FillingStyle -> 
  MapIndexed[#2 -> Directive[Opacity[0.3], #] &, colors]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I propose making an extension to the definition of `Plot`.  [I have done this before.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4716/121)

```
toDirective[{ps__} | ps__] := Flatten[Directive @@ Flatten[{#}]] & /@ {ps}

makefills = MapIndexed[#2 -> Join @@ toDirective@{Opacity[0.3], #} &, #] &;

Unprotect[Plot];
Plot[a__, b : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{$FSmatch = True},
    With[{fills = makefills@OptionValue[PlotStyle]}, 
      Plot[a, FillingStyle -> fills, b]
  ]] /; ! TrueQ[$FSmatch] /; OptionValue[FillingStyle] === "Match"
```

With this in place, you can use `FillingStyle -> "Match"` to auto-style the fills to match the main styles.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Log[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2},
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashing[{0.04, 0.01}]},
                {Thick, Dashed, Orange},
                {Darker@Green, Thick}},
  Filling -> Axis,
  FillingStyle -> "Match"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like

```
With[{colours = {Red, Green, Blue}},
 Plot[Evaluate@
   MapThread[
    Function[{\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, 
     PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], Sqrt[\[Sigma]]], x]], 
     {{priorMean, llhMean, postMean}, {priorVar, llhVar, postVar}}], 
  {x, 0, 100},
  Filling -> 
    MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> {Axis, Directive[Opacity[.3, #1]]} &, colours], 
  PlotStyle -> colours]]
```

[image: filling with different colours]

Answer (score 3):

This gets a result:

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  MapThread[
   Function[{\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], Sqrt[\[Sigma]]], x]], {{priorMean, 
     llhMean, postMean}, {priorVar, llhVar, postVar}}], {x, 0, 100}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Red}, 2 -> {Axis, Green}, 3 -> {Axis, Blue}},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

Found in the help under FillingStyle, Scope, Filling Style.

And alternatively:

```
f = MapThread[
   Function[{\[Mu], \[Sigma]}, 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], Sqrt[\[Sigma]]], x]],
   {{priorMean, llhMean, postMean}, {priorVar, llhVar, postVar}}];
c = {Red, Green, Blue};
Show[Array[
  Plot[f[[#]], {x, 0, 100}, Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, c[[#]]}}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, 0.08}, PlotStyle -> c[[#]]] &, 3]]
```

[image]